# Does every non-compact Riemann surface embed holomorphically into $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables, complex-manifolds

> **Question:** Can every non-compact Riemann surface be holomorphically embedded into $\mathbb{C}^2$?  If not, what are some (all?) of the obstructions to such an embedding?

This question is partially inspired by the Wikipedia page on [Stein manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_manifold), which taught me two things:

- Behnke-Stein Theorem (1948): Every non-compact Riemann surface is Stein, hence can be holomorphically embedded in some $\mathbb{C}^N$.
- Every Stein manifold of complex dimension $n$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}^{2n+1}$ by a biholomorphic proper map.  (It would be nice to have a citation for this.)

Together, these two theorems imply that every non-compact Riemann surface holomorphically embeds into $
\mathbb{C}^3$.  This raises the question of embedding into $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: A citation for the second theorem: E. Bishop, _Mappings of partially analytic spaces_, Amer. J. Math. **83**, 209-242 (1961); and R. Narasimhan, _Imbedding of holomorphically complete convex spaces_, Amer. J. Math. **82**, 917-934 (1960). These appear to be the foundational papers on this (can't dig them out of the library right now, sorry!), found via Cieliebak and Eliashberg's book _From Stein to Weinstein and Back_, specifically Chapter 5, theorem 15. I would recommend paging through the book, too - it can be found on Cieliebak's website.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221957/is-there-a-complex-surface-into-which-every-riemann-surface-embeds

Comment: I found this [Stein manifolds.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~schleissinger/stein2018/Stein%20manifolds.pdf) to show an immersion into $\mathbb{C}^N$ exists they simply say that for any compact $K \subset X $ and $N \ge 2\dim(X)+1$ the subset of $\mathcal{O}(X,\mathbb{C}^N)$ that are not injective $K \to \mathbb{C}^N$ is closed with empty interior, thus the subset of $\mathcal{O}(X,\mathbb{C}^N)$ that are not injective $X \to \mathbb{C}^N$ is contained in a countably infinite union of closed sets with empty interior, so it is not the whole of $\mathcal{O}(X,\mathbb{C}^N)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an important open problem going back to Forster, Bell and Narasimhan. To quote from

A. Alarcón, F.  Forstnerič, 
Every bordered Riemann surface is a complete proper curve in a ball, 
Mathematische Annalen, Vol. 357 (2013) Issue 3, 1049–1070.

> "It is classical that any open Riemann surface immerses properly holomorphically into ${\mathbb C}^2$, but it is an open question whether it embeds into ${\mathbb C}^2$."

Existence of proper and non-proper embeddings are both unknown. 
Many things are known. For instance, the complement to any finite collection of pairwise disjoint closed topological disks in a genus 1 compact Riemann surface (aka a torus or an elliptic curve) embeds:

E. F. Wold, Embedding subsets of tori properly into ${\mathbb C}^2$. Ann. Inst. Fourier (Grenoble) 57 (2007), no. 5, 1537–1555.

It is also known that there are no topological obstructions to a  holomorphic embedding of an open Riemann surface in ${\mathbb C}^2$:

A. Alarcón, F. López, Proper holomorphic embeddings of Riemann surfaces with arbitrary topology into ${\mathbb C}^2$. J. Geom. Anal. 23 (2013), no. 4, 1794–1805.

and

A. Alarcón, J. Globevnik, Complete embedded complex curves in the ball of ${\mathbb C}^2$ can have any topology. Anal. PDE 10 (2017), no. 8, 1987–1999.

See [these slides](http://wpd.ugr.es/~geometry/seminar/files/talks/AAlarc%C3%B3n20111005.pdf) for further background on this problem.